# How to copy string to clipboard Powershell? Linux/Windows/Mac

Tags: powershell, cross-platform, clipboard, powershell-5.0, powershell-v6.0

I'm in the process of writing a powershell module, that aim to be distributed and I'm looking for a **cross-platform (Win/Linux/MacOS) powershell `≥5.0`** solution to copy a generated string to the system's clipboard.

#### Env

```
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.1.2
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.1.2
OS                             Linux 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

#### `Set-Clipboard`

```powershell
PS ~/projects/lesspass-powershell> Get-Random | Set-Clipboard
Set-Clipboard : The term 'Set-Clipboard' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-Random | Set-Clipboard
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo
: ObjectNotFound        : (Set-Clipboard:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

#### `Write-Clipboard`

```powershell
PS ~/projects/lesspass-powershell> Get-Random | Write-Clipboard
Write-Clipboard : The term 'Write-Clipboard' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-Random | Write-Clipboard
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo
: ObjectNotFound        : (Write-Clipboard:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

#### `Out-Clipboard`

```powershell
PS ~/projects/lesspass-powershell> Get-Random | Out-Clipboard
Out-Clipboard : The term 'Out-Clipboard' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-Random | Out-Clipboard
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo
: ObjectNotFound        : (Out-Clipboard:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: To get the standard `Get-Clipboard` and `Set-Clipboard` working in Linux, you need to install xclip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution: install module

You can install aditionnal module [`ClipboardText`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ClipboardText/0.1.7)

#### Locate command

On Windows (PS `v5.1`) to know which module contains these command :

```
PS> get-module | ?{$_.ExportedCommands.Keys -like '*-Clipboard'}

    ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
    ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
    Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
    Script     3.2.0.0    Pscx                                {Add-PathVariable, Clear-MSMQueue, Convert-Xml, ConvertFrom-Base64...}
```

However, this results is empty on PS `v6.1 core`!

```
get-module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management,pscx | ?{$_.ExportedCommands.Keys -like '*-Clipboard'}
```